# PowerTools in Chrome 2013 SP1 Issue?

Tags: cme, powertools, chrome

I installed `PowerTools` to my **Windows Server 2012 R2/Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1** environment from here [code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/). 

Then proceed to refresh my TCM within Chrome (Version 41.0.2272.89 m) and I can confirm that I see the newly added PowerTools item in the Ribbon toolbar with all of it's tools; however, none of the icons appear enabled nor can I right-click and utilize any of the tools. 
I have also created a custom page entitled PowerTools with url /PowerTools. After further browser testing, it seems Chrome specific as it works in both FireFox (32.0.3) and IE 10.

Does anyone else also experience this with `PowerTools` in Chrome for `Tridion 2013 SP1` ?

Chrome:

[image]

FireFox:

[image]

Comment: Did you clear the browser cache (preferably by increasing the @modification attribute in System.config so that all clients refresh their cache automatically)? I don't believe the current installer does that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @PeterKjaer - By clearing my browser cache in Chrome, PowerTools is appearing and working as expected. 
[image]